# ios sqlite connect to database and retrieve value

Tags: ios, iphone, database, sqlite

I have an SQLite database which contains three columns: `ID`, `Name`, `Dept`. I have one main `ViewController` in which I have three fields: `enter mobileNumber` (a textField), `Name` (a label), and  `Dept` (a label). When i enter first 4 digit of any number in the textfield, the two labels automatically show the relevant value from the database. i am getting output fine when i give a default value in database. what i need is without giving any default value in database i want to run my app directly when i enter any number it should show the value of Name and Dept to the label. My database contains more than 3000 records.

i am using this query to get data from database:

```
sqlStatement = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT _id,Name,Dept FROM Codes
    WHERE _id=\'%@\'",idString.text]UTF8String];
```

Comment: have you verified that your id field is in form of string in database? it should not be in integer as per your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LIKE Clause` which will return relative outputs.

```
 sqlStatement = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT _id,Name,Dept FROM Codes WHERE _id like '%%@'",idString.text]UTF8String];
```

It will return you matching results as per your id.

For more clarity on `LIKE Clause`  please check this [Link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm).

Comment: r u sure %%@ will return values, i tried but still in error

Comment: Yes try that it should return all values starting with your query string.

Comment: can u give some alternate methods plz i tried its not working

Answer (score 0):

I Assume

1. You are running a query with the first 4 digits
2. In case of more than a single match to the database, you are selecting one of the rows returned by the query

Things to try to debug this:

1. Debug the query: Programmatically, write a query using 4 digits of a number that returns only one row. Check that the query returns what you expected according to your data source.
2. Debug displaying information: Hardcode that query and show that you can display the Name and Dept. information.

Comment: i am already tried that giveing one sam[le ID in textfield and run it. its working but what i need is when i type instantly any number it should matches the database and show me the result in two labels

Comment: Are you certain that when you enter another number, your query returns at least one entry? And that entry has valid values?